# Keras - training and validation loss for CNN

Tags: keras, tf.keras

- I am using Keras to train my CNN with simulated images on the fly using **train_on_batch** command and can get the training loss.
- Next run- I am predicting the Precision and recall using my  pretrained  CNN (own architecture) for the prediction of my results where i split my data again into training and test datasets using the command 
  **predictions = model.predict(np.array(images), batch_size=batch_size)** .

  I wish to get the validation loss and i am unsure how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can visualize the loss or the accuracy on your model by means of the next lines:

```
history = model.fit(your_parameters) / model.fit_generator(your_parameters) 

# visualizing losses and accuracy
train_loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss   = history.history['val_loss']
train_acc  = history.history['acc']
val_acc    = history.history['val_acc']
```

You just need to take into consideration that `model.fit()` or `model.fit_generator()` return an object, in this case `history` object.

Then you can access the parameters of this `history` object like above.

Comment: Why use model.fit(your_parameters) / model.fit_generator(your_parameters) instead of model.fit(your_parameters)  as it produces the history. I have another question regarding the ouput from the model.fit command. Does it produces the 'loss' after it completes all epochs or is it stored after every epoch?

Comment: I did not say you must use generator. Only told you that you can use it. And it produces the loss after it completes all epochs set it model.fit()

Comment: Thanks timbus. I mistook the '/' for divide.

Comment: Also please don't forget to also upvote the answer if it helped you, thank you.